# Node Class inside the LinkedList class

Tags: c++, linked-list

I want to create a class of LinkedList and I have to put the class of Node inside of the class of LinkedList, how do you prefer me to do it?

I think something like:

```
Class LinkedList {
  private:
    class Node* head;
  public:
    class Node {
      private:
        int data;
        Node* next;  
        Node* prev;
    };
};
```

but I think this is not good.

Comment: in C++ every name must have been declared before being used. you *can* write `struct Node* head;` in order to declare `Node` on-the-fly, but instead, rearrange the code.

Comment: you are right, I changed it..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do it like this

```
class LinkedList {
  private:
    struct Node {
        int data;
        Node* next;  
        Node* prev;
    };
    Node* head;
  public:
    ...
};
```

No need for anything in Node to be private since it's not useable outside of LinkedList.

Comment: nice idea.. but struct is in C, doesn't it? I think to define it as Class, but then I will have to define a lot of functions of get, set, in the public of the both classes..

Comment: A struct is C and C++. There's very little difference in C++ between a struct and a class. You can define get and set functions in a struct as well if you want. The main difference between a struct and a class is that everything in a struct is public by efault, and in a class it's private by default. But again you can have private items in a struct and public items in a class.